# JQuery / Javascript - How to find the index of a table header by the header text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

What is a good way to find the index of column by it's display text?

e.g.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Age</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to have something like

```
var nameIndex = getColIndex('Name'); // nameIndex = 1
```

Is there a quick / good way to do it? (Doesn't have to be jQuery, but would be nice)

Comment: I'd be curious to know the larger context of your question. Are you anticipating the `Name` to be in a different column, or will it always be in `1`?

Comment: Yep, the column might move around... that's why I wanted to find it by name (which is immutable)

Comment: Will it be possible for other columns to contain a substring of `Name`? Or how about whitespace. Is there any chance that there could be leading or trailing whitespace, like line breaks?

Comment: Good questions. I guess it should be exact match... I like your thinking

Comment: So many things that could go wrong. ;-) If there could be leading/trailing space, then do `$.trim($(this).text()) == 'Name'` Or a slightly more optimized version would be `$.trim($.text([this])) == 'Name'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following both seem to work, in Chromium 17/Ubuntu 11.04:

```
$('tr td').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).text() == 'Name';
    }).index();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8aaW/).

Or:

```
$('td:contains("Name")').index();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8aaW/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to OP's question, in comments, below:

> but how do I limit it to the first row?

To limit it to the first row, simply use the `:first` selector:

```
$('tr:first td')
```

Giving:

```
$('tr:first td').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).text() == 'Name';
    }).index();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8aaW/2/).

References:

- [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I limit it to the first row? this is where I got a little confused

Comment: I added this to your solution to limit to the first row... 

var index = $('tr:eq(0) td:contains("Name")').index();

http://jsfiddle.net/9uPWe/

Comment: The selector would be $('tr:eq(0) td')

Comment: @trante: I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//select the first TR element, then select its children (the TDs),
//then filter them down to only the one that contains a certain string
var theIndex = $('tr').first().children().filter(function () {
    return ($(this).text() == 'ID');
}).index();
```

When passing `.filter()` a function, if you return `true` for an index, then it will be kept in the selection, and if you return `false` then that index will be removed from the selection: http://api.jquery.com/filter

This will limit the search to the first row and give the index of the column with the specified search text (this code used `ID`).

Note that `.index()`, when used like above, will return the index of the current selection based on its sibling elements: http://api.jquery.com/index

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/FdhcV/

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').click(function(){
        $('td').each(function(index){
            if ($(this).text() == $('#lookup').val()){
                console.log(index)
            }
        });    
    });   
});​
```